# CoreData: how to create and save objects inside `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I would like to react to modified NSManagedObjects, therefore I setup an observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    ...
}
```

But I didn't find a solution yet how to create objects inside that block.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in
    let context = notification.object as! NSManagedObjectContext
    context.perform {
        let insertedObjects = notification.userInfo?[NSInsertedObjectsKey] as? Set<NSManagedObject> ?? Set<NSManagedObject>()
        // insertedObjects are empty (outside of context.perform they are NOT EMPTY
    }
}
```

Also when I do not use `context.perform` I do get `attempt to recursively call -save: on the context aborted`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should only use (iOS) version specific tags if your question is concerned specifically about changes introduced in a specific version of the technology the tag is related to or if your issue only started occurring on a specific version. However, tagging 3 different iOS version rarely seem justifiable...

Comment: ok, sorry - I meant that it's iOS 10 and upwards related as I'm using the "new" Core Data stack

Comment: creating objects is another thing. your property `let insertedObjects` gives you inserted objects with this change, if there are any.